# Call requires API level 23 (current min is 18): android.app.Activity#requestPermissions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

The error is showing in this "checkSelfPermission" Function

This is my code:

```
private void checkBTPermissions() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            int permissionCheck =
            this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");

           permissionCheck+=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");

          if (permissionCheck != 0) {

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission Check is only available from API 23 i.e. from Marshmallow.

You don't need to ask for Permission on Api < 23 as they are automatically granted on App Install.

More Info - 

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-runtime-permissions

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong at the following code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {}
```

**`Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` = 21**. You can ask runtime permissions only for API level > 22.

Fix it by changing your code into:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {}
```

Or even better way would be to use my [library.](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions) :)